# Using Gson#fromJson to Convert jsonString to Class

Tags: java, json, gson, apache-httpclient-4.x, steam

I have this json class:
http://pastebin.com/kSiTdSSC

For this json string:
http://pastebin.com/CrpuUPFr

But when I do:

```
TradeResult tradeResult = tradeUser.gson.fromJson(response, TradeResult.class);
```

It returns all the values null.

Which one of my variables in the TradeResponse class are incorrect? Could it be because response.descriptions.descriptions has two different types of objects? If so how do I fix it?

Comment: The values of what? What is `null` here?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the response variable, so everything inside that (everything) is also null.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. This is probably caused by the inner classes. Make them `static` or move them to their own file. Newer versions of Gson don't care, but you might be using something older.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using the latest version (2.7) of gson. Tried to set all classes static, but tradeResult.response still returns null

Comment: Verify what your `response` contains because this works fine for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so you are able to parse the string with this class and it doesnt give any errors?

Comment: There are no errors and the only members that are null are the ones missing from the json.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can I see your implementation?

Comment: I copy pasted the code in your links (which you should copy into your question by the way), put the JSON in a file and called `fromJson(new FileReader("myfile"), TradeResult.class)`.